# Calling member function of other controller in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to call the member function of another controller in zend framework, if yes then how?

```
<?php
class FirstController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
         // general action 
    }   

    public function memberFunction() {
         // a resuable function
    }
}
```

Here's another controller

```
<?php
class SecondController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public indexAction() {
         // here i need to call memberFunction() of FirstController
    }
}
```

Please explain how i can access memberFunction() from second controller.

## Solution

Better idea is to define a AppController and make all usual controllers to extend AppController which further extends Zend_Controller_Action.

```
class AppController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function memberFunction() {
         // a resuable function
    }
}

class FirstController extends AppController {
    public function indexAction() {
         // call function from any child class
         $this->memberFunction();
    } 
}
```

Now `memberFunction` can be invoked from controllers extending `AppController` as a rule of simple inheritance.

Comment: Just an FYI, I definitely prefer to setup shared classes or modules when I need common functionality. However, I ran into one situation using ZF2 where it would be quite helpful to use a parent AppController that is extended on a couple other controllers. Your solution worked nicely. In ZF2 you setup:"class AppController extends AbstractActionController" and the child controller would be the same: "class FirstController extends AppController"  I know there are better ways to do this and I should probably rethink some app structure, but it works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Controllers aren't designed to be used in that way. If you want to execute an *action* of the other controller *after* your current controller, use the `_forward()` method:

```
// Invokes SecondController::otherActionAction() after the current action has been finished.
$this->_forward('other-action', 'second');
```

Note that this only works for *action methods* (“memberAction”), not arbitrary member functions!

If `SecondController::memberFunction()` does something that is needed across multiple controllers, put that code in a action helper or library class, so that both controllers can access the shared functionality without having to depend on each other.

Comment: UPDATE 2015: $this->_forward() is deprecated since ZF 1.7 - use $this->forward() instead.

Comment: Hmmm, as of this writing, the [1.12](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html) docs still reference _forward(). But you're right: the code clearly shows `_forward` as deprecated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should consider factoring out the code into either an action helper or to your model so that it can be called from both controllers that need it.

Regards,

Rob...

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to follow DRY and move those functions to common library place. For example create in library folder

```
My/Util/
```

and file

```
CommonFunctions.php
```

then call your class

```
My_Util_CommonFunctions
```

and define your methods

Now you can call them from any place in the code using your new namespace which you have to register.

```
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace(array('My_'));
```

in any controller you can call your custom methods by using:

```
My_Util_CustomFunctions::yourCustomMethod($params);
```