# How do I call other Controllers within a Zend Framework Process and retrieve their rendered view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller, message-queue

I have the following setup:

An endless running PHP process that looks at a job queue which contains module names, controller names, action names and a parameter array.

For every job I want to call the given controllers action and retrieve the rendered view for further processing.

I was thinking about bootstrapping an instance of Zend_Application for every job but not exactly sure on how to handle the rest. Maybe there is also a better way.

So my question is:

How do I call other Controllers within a Zend Framework Process and retrieve their rendered view?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think taking the Front_Controller and dispatching a new request would be the best to do.

Something like this, from your controller (not working code):

```
    $frontController = $this->getFrontController();

    $newRequest = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
    $newRequest->setActionName('newAction');
    $newRequest->setControllerName('newController');

    $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();

    $frontController->dispatch($newRequest, $response);
```

It might not be this simple, but something to think about...

Comment: it worked: $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$this->getFrontController()->setResponse(new Zend_Controller_Response_Cli)->setRequest($request->setControllerName('testController')->setActionName('testAction'))->setRouter(new Zend_Controller_Router_Route)->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);
 … thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_forward('otherAction', 'otherControllerOrNull');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.dispatcher.html

You can read this thread : [Calling member function of other controller in zend framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886291/calling-member-function-of-other-controller-in-zend-framework)

Comment: But this would forward the existing request to the specified controller/action, right? It sounds to me like OP wants to capture the output from that controller/action for use in the *current* request.

Comment: Thats right David, I want to keep the current process running and just work with whatever output has been produced by the other controller. _forward will not allow this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this favo?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use an [Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action)? If you want the output in your controller then you can simply use `$this->view->action('someAction', 'someController');` or the ActionStack helper.

In either case, be aware of the performance implications though. See [Why the Zend Framework Actionstack is Evil](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/) for more details.