# calling an action from the default module in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I have the following structure of folders in Zend Framework:

```
Application
- default
-- controllers
--- mailController.php
- modules
-- asegurados
--- controllers
---- indexController.php
```

I have an action in mailController which sends a mail (sendmailAction), and I want to send the exact mail in indexController in a function called sendmailAction. How can I call from IndexController::sendmailAction() to MailController::sendmailAction()?

I've tried the following:

```
/** indexController.php **/
public function sendformatosAction() {
    ...
    $M = new MailController();
    $M->sendmailAction();   
    ...
}
```

But it seems that it's not loading the proper class. Can you help me, please? thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling member function of other controller in zend framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886291/calling-member-function-of-other-controller-in-zend-framework)

Comment: nope. The difference is in the controller inside the default folder.

Comment: ZF2?  ZF1?  Anyway...  `_forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null):` See the part about module?  Also, sounds like it should maybe be an action helper?

Comment: ZF2, thank you. I've tried that, it didn't worked.

Comment: Seems its been answered here on SO.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180839/is-it-possible-to-forward-data-to-another-controller-action-in-zend-2  If that is not working then tell us what error message / warning you get.

Comment: The thing is that I get no warnings or errors at all. My call is like this: `$this->_forward('sendmailAction','mailController',NULL,NULL);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80604/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-kyomu).